# Is it possible for a button to open into a specific tab when using the Tab Bar Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

The question is a little confusing to articulate so hopefully an image will be a little more helpful. Here's the setup:

[image]

So, I want the *First View* button to open the `FirstViewController`, and I want the *Second View* button to open the `SecondViewController`. If I link the *Second View* button to the `SecondViewController` like this:

[image]

I lose the tab navigation. And if I connect the button to the `TabViewController` like this:

[image]

then it will automatically open into the `FirstViewController`. Unless I'm missing something, it seems like this would need to be done with a little extra code but I cannot seem to find anything that explains how to do this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create storyboard segue from `Viewcontroller` to `TabBarController` with an identifier. Then assign `selelctedIndex` value of TabBarController in `prepareforsegue` method

[image: storyboard]

```
@IBAction func firstBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    (sender as! UIButton).tag = 0
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "tabBar", sender: sender)
}
@IBAction func secBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    (sender as! UIButton).tag = 1
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "tabBar", sender: sender)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "tabBar" {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? UITabBarController {
            vc.selectedIndex = (sender as! UIButton).tag
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In tabViewController you need to implement following functions..

```
var index : Int!

@IBAction func button1(_ sender: Any) {
        index = 1
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "TabBarSegue", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func button2(_ sender: Any) {
        index = 2
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "TabBarSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if(segue.identifier == "TabBarSegue"){
            let videoController : TabBarController = segue.destination as! TabBarController
            videoController.index = index
}
```

Then you need to implement TabBarController and implement following..

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    var index : Int!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        selectedIndex = index

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```